# What is the proper way to register a user profile?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Right now I have in my admin.py code which is generating an error when I try to use django.db.models.User which is where I'm guessing https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/ is talking about. My admin.py presently reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=UTF-8

import django.contrib.admin
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
import django.db.models
from pim_accounts.models import UserProfile

django.contrib.admin.autodiscover()

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user = instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender = django.db.models.User,
  dispatch_uid = 'create_user_profile')
```

With the whole project at http://JonathansCorner.com/project/pim.tgz.

What is the correct and preferred way of setting things so that a pim_accounts.models.UserProfile is set as the user profile for all accounts?

The error (plus environment settings) is:

```
AttributeError at /accounts/login/
    'module' object has no attribute 'User'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'module' object has no attribute 'User'
Exception Location: /Users/jonathan/pim/../pim/admin.py in <module>, line 15
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/jonathan/pim',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-0.8.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
Installed Applications:
  ['django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.sites',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'pim',
   'pim_accounts',
   'pim_calendar',
   'pim_scratchpad']
Installed Middleware:
  ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
Server time:    Thu, 16 Feb 2012 10:29:54 -0600
```

Detailed Error Message

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  250.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
  279.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
  274.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/jonathan/pim/../pim/urls.py" in <module>
  2. import admin
File "/Users/jonathan/pim/../pim/admin.py" in <module>
  15. post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender = django.db.models.User,

Exception Type: AttributeError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'User'
```

Comment: If you have an error, post the error message. Always. We can't help you if we don't know what the actual problem is.

Comment: `User` is in the `django.contrib.auth.models` package, not `django.db.models`.

Answer (score 1):

I just use `User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])`. This will create a profile when you try to access `user.profile` if it doesn't exist. You should also set `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` to the model you're using for profiles in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to import User from django.db.models rather than django.contrib.auth.models, try:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User, 
    dispatch_uid='create_user_profile')
```